# I can't get a Waiting mouse cursor with OpenFileDialog, whatever I try

Tags: c#, .net, cursor, openfiledialog

I want my user to open files and I use the OpenFileDialog class for that in C#. Sometimes it takes a while before the filedialog to open files appears. I set a waiting cursor to inform the user that things take a while, but it is not showing. In fact, I see the cursor change very briefly in a waiting cursor, but then it returns to normal, while the open file dialog is still not showing.

I started out with things like:

```cs
Cursor = Cursors.Waiting;
```

which works fine for all lengthy operations in my application, but not for the OpenFileDialog.
Searching the Internet, and mostly SO, I found a better way to do this:

```
Application.UseWaitCursor = true;
// open file dialog
Application.UseWaitCursor = false;
```

but that doesn't do the job either... I tried the last option with and without the Application prefix, but neither gives the desired result.

I've even found some custom WaitCursor class on another site and implemented that, but to no avail.

This is what I have now (and doesn't work):

```cs
public string[] LetUserChoosePdfFiles()
{
    string[] pdfFileNames;

    Application.UseWaitCursor = true;   // this doesn't work for the OpenFileDialog and can't find a solution on the Internet?

    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        openFileDialog.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = false;
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pdfFileNames = openFileDialog.FileNames;
        }
        else
        {
            pdfFileNames = null;
        }
    }

    Application.UseWaitCursor = false;

    return pdfFileNames;
}
```

Comment: If the openFileDialog.ShowDialog() method take time to open it will likely hangs the main thread of the app, so the mouse cursor is not updated too. In this case you need a "wait form" that live on a different thread,

Comment: I think you can change the Cursor Property on the Form instead of Application.UseWaitCursor

Comment: @ElmoDev001: Hmmm, I'm not sure. The point of showing a wait cursor is that the the main thread of the app is busy and the user must be informed of that, right? And how would a "wait form" that calls the OpenFileDialog change the cursor when that takes a long time? I still want to inform the user that something is working and he/she should be patient.

Comment: @Roxana Sh: did that, didn't work. Changed it later to Application.UseWaitCursor, which also didn't work? (And, after your question verified again that this doesn't work...)

Comment: what about Cursor.Current property?  you would set the Cursor.Current property to a wait cursor

Comment: @Roxana Sh: also tried that. It's what I started out with, until I noticed the cursor didn't change. I went looking on Internet for other possibilities and came back with 'UseWaitCursor' is the best way to change the cursor. But appearently not for the OpenFileDialog...

Answer (score 0):

I got successful results with this method.

```
Application.DoEvents();
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    // transactions

    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}
```